# how to set saturation in cv::Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv, hsv

I use a function

```
void maxBright(Mat img){
    cvtColor(img, img, CV_BGR2HSV);
    cvSet(&(IplImage)img, cvScalar(0,100,0, 0));
    cvtColor(img, img, CV_HSV2BGR);
}
```

after this I tryed to use a

```
void maxBright(Mat img){
    cvtColor(img, img, CV_BGR2HSV);
    Mat hsvChannels[3];
    for(int y(0); y < img.rows; ++y)
    {
        for(int x(0); x < img.cols; ++x)
            hsvChannels[1].at<uchar>(y, x) = 100;
    }
    cvtColor(img, img, CV_HSV2BGR);
}
```

but I'm shure, bouth of it set a Green value in BGR. How to fix this?

Comment: 1) do not use opencv's legacy c-api. 2) you're writing into a (useless)copy. hsvChannels is never used.  try : `img.atVec3b>(y, x, 1) = 100; // fill saturation channel`

Comment: @berak, I tryed this:
void maxBright(Mat img){
 cvtColor(img, img, CV_BGR2HSV);

 for(int y(0); y < img.rows; ++y)
 {
  for(int x(0); x < img.cols; ++x)
   img.at<Vec3b> (y, x, 1) = 100;
 }

 cvtColor(img, img, CV_HSV2BGR);
}

There are some mistake with memory, it always link me to Mat::prt

Comment: If you're doing it this way, then: convert to HSV, split into three channels, modify the saturation channel, and `merge()` the channels back, then convert to BGR.